# How to specify domains in NewsAPI request?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to use [NewsAPI](https://newsapi.org/) to get a list of all news articles from a certain source about a certain topic, however when I try to specify the sources or the domains, it doesn't actually filter the response to those sources. I'm trying to implement this in C#, this is a snippet of what I have so far:

```
  List<string> domains = new List<string> { "https://www.espn.com/" };
  var response = await newsApiClient.GetEverythingAsync(new EverythingRequest
  {
    Q = "Bowling",
    Domains = domains,
    SortBy = SortBys.Relevancy,
    Language = Languages.EN,
    From = new DateTime(2020, 4, 15)
  });
```

The documentation on their site specifies that domain should be:

> A comma-seperated string of domains (eg bbc.co.uk, techcrunch.com, engadget.com) to restrict the search to.

My linter is telling domains should be List< string>, so I'm not exactly sure why it's not accepting the filter.

Comment: what is exactly `NewsAPI` ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in the library. In NewsApiClient.cs there is

> queryParams.Add("domains=" + string.Join(",", request.Sources));

But there should be

> queryParams.Add("domains=" + string.Join(",", request.Domains));

There is a pull request for this: https://github.com/News-API-gh/News-API-csharp/pull/2

You can fork the repository, make those changes and build it yourself.